# WindowManager removeView throws "Hardware acceleration ..." exception

Tags: java, android, exception

I have the following code:

```
protected View progressView;
protected LayoutParams progressParams;

class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Result> {
    String timeleft;
    String error;

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(String... s) {          
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        getWindowManager().addView(progressView, progressParams);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {           
        getWindowManager().removeView(progressView); // throws exception
        // ...
    }
}
```

This error do I get on my phone (not in the emulator). Perhaps because I use the HTC HD2 Android ROM from tyween which has lot of stuff enabled and "lives on the edge".

```
03-02 22:53:08.303: E/test(5573): Exception: Hardware acceleration can only be used with a single UI thread.
03-02 22:53:08.303: E/test(5573): Original thread: Thread[main,5,main]
03-02 22:53:08.303: E/test(5573): Current thread: Thread[background thread,5,main]
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Is it possible that you manually call onPostExecute from doInBackground?

Comment: No that is not the case. Quite a regular AsyncTask usage actually...

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be avoided by putting android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in the application tag in your manifest. But it doesn't solve the problem of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the view in your UI thread.